# How to access multiple elements of array in one go?

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array `uint8_t data[256]`. But each element is single byte.
My data bus is 32 bit long. So, If I want to access 32 bits, I do:

```
DATA = data[i] + (data[i + 1] << 8) + (data[i + 2] << 16) + (data[i + 3] << 24);
```

But this translates into 4 separate read requests in the memory of one byte each.

How can I access all the 4 bytes in the form of single transaction?

Comment: If `data` is of type `int [256]`, not only one byte is read for each summand.

Comment: You would have to be using a very non-standard compiler to have `int data[256];` be composed of single-bytes.  The 'bytes' would have to be at least 16 bits each (CHAR_BIT == 16).  There is some confusion in the assumptions you're making, I think.  If, as one of your comments suggests, you mean `uint8_t data[256];`, then one question is 'are you going to index at values of `i` that are not multiples of 4'? and another question is 'what happens if you try to access an 'improperly aligned' memory address as a 4-byte unit?'  You need to know the answers to both before risking short-cuts.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the endian-ness of your data (or if you don't care), and your data is aligned (or have a byte-addressing process and you don't care about efficiency) you can cast data to a `uint32_t *` and access it in 4-byte chucks, like so:

```
DATA = ((uint32_t *)data)[i/4];
```

This of course assumes `i` is a multiple of 4.

Comment: You should be more precise: If you know the target architecture to be little-endian.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast `data` to `uint32_t`.

```
uint8_t data[256] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int index = 1 ;
  uint32_t d = *(uint32_t *)(data + index) ;
  printf ("%08x\n", d) ;
}
```

Output on a little endian architecture will be

```
05040302
```

Output on a big endian architecture will be

```
02030405
```

However depending on the achitecture of the processor your progam is running on, you might run into memory alignment problems (performance hit if you address an unaligned memory, or even a crash if your processor doesn't support unaligned memory addressing).

Comment: I tried this and this almost worked: The data that I have is 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08... When I access the first location as      *(long *)(data+0), I get 0x01030201 instead of 0x04030201. And when I access *(long *) (data+1), I get 0x05040302. This means data[4]=4, But the value returned is incorrect, do you have any idea, why this is the case?

Comment: The code works fine here. Ask a new question on stackoverflow with this specific issue.

Comment: Will the output depend on the chip architecture? I was under the impression that the output will be architecture-independent, just like bit-shifting, etc. This would explain why @Rgarg got 0x05040302 and not the little-endian representation even though he/she is likely on a chip using little-endian representation under the hood.

Comment: `uint32_t d = *(uint32_t *)(data + index) ;` with `index = 1` is an unaligned access, with potential undefined behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie that was already mentioned in the last sentence of the answer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: indeed you mention it as a possibility, but given the index value, the probability is quite high for an unaligned memory access, which, as you say, may or may not cause a crash depending on the architecture and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should store data as an array of 32-bit:

```
uint32_t data[64];
DATA = data[i];
DATA = data[i+1];
...
```

Comment: I cannot modify the array. Its a constraint. But if we look at it, from the memory perspective, isn't it the same thing? uint32_t data[64] and uint8_t data[256]?

Comment: @Rgarg: What is the type of your array? In the question, you say `int data[256];` but here in your comment you seem to be saying `uint8_t data[256];` — these are very different!  It makes a wreck out of your question, in fact.

Answer (score -1):

As @dwayne-towell mentioned - you need to care of endianness of you data. In one transaction it might be realized like an example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int
main()
{
        uint8_t data[256];
        uint32_t i, *p;

        // Add some 32bit numbers
        p = (uint32_t *)data;
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(data)/sizeof(uint32_t); ++i) {
                *(p++) = i;
        }

        // Print some 32bit numbers
        p = (uint32_t *)data;
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(data)/sizeof(uint32_t); ++i) {
                printf("value=%u\n", *(p++));
        }

        return (0);
}
```